# How to put tooltip for an id dynamically using javascript? how to add jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-tooltip

I know how get tooltip from html tags, but what I need here is I got to generate tooltip dynamically.

Tell me how to add plug ins for this purpose...

I've code like this:

```
<div id = "MyID">ABC</div>
```

And after some operation I want to put tooltip to MYID like this:

```
$("#MyID").tooltip({
  content: "Awesome Tooltip!"
});
```

Throwing an error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
```

Comment: Make sure to load tool tip plug-in first. I guess it is a part of jquery ui. Download it and add it.

Comment: How to do that? I'm new Please do help

Comment: Look at this example: https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/